# Did model.fit() initiate model's weights in keras?

Tags: python, keras

1.

```py
model = Model(inPut, outputs=outPut)
model.compile(loss="mse", optimizer="adam")
for i in range(10):
   model.fit(dataX, dataY, epochs=EPOCH, batch_size=BATCHSIZE, verbose=0, shuffle=False)
   #save model
```

2.

```py
model = Model(inPut, outputs=outPut)
for i in range(10):
   model.compile(loss="mse", optimizer="adam")
   model.fit(dataX, dataY, epochs=EPOCH, batch_size=BATCHSIZE, verbose=0, shuffle=False)
   #save model
```

3.

```py
for i in range(10):
   model = Model(inPut, outputs=outPut)
   model.compile(loss="mse", optimizer="adam")
   model.fit(dataX, dataY, epochs=EPOCH, batch_size=BATCHSIZE, verbose=0, shuffle=False)
   #save model
```

I studied neural network in keras.

i want that each iteration is each learning.

but second(third.. fourth..) iteration learning(model.fit) is going continually fisrt learning(model.fit)

loss is going continually in three code.

could you tell me some method that each iteration is each learning?

each iteration model is another model.

Comment: I am unsure as to what you're after.  Do you simply want to continue with using `fit` after `EPOCH` epochs?  `model.fit` resumes training from the last epoch so if I understand what you want, it's already doing what you want.

Comment: I want that each model is different in interation.

but in my code each for-statement same model.

after first model save, when i train second model, model was already training(The first model continues to apply).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it is your intent to create differently trained models but maintain the same architecture, then your code snippet for #3 is the one you're after.  You create a new model using the same architecture, configure the neural network then train it.  After each iteration, make sure you save the model.

Comment: However, when I use the #3, I get the same result as the #1 and #1.

Comment: Then there's something wrong with your code elsewhere.  Please provide your full code so that it's reproducible.  As is, no one can reproduce your findings.